# How can I tell if my home router can host a public site

Tags: networking, router, webserver

I have a dedicated computer running debian. I have nginx up and running on it (can access it locally no problem via 192.168.x.x). I've put that machine in the DMZ on my router (Bell Home Hub 1000).

I go here http://www.t1shopper.com/, put in my public ip address and it says "[my ip address] is responding on port 80 (http)".

However when I go there in my browser, it times out "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

What are some ways that I can debug this situation? The server is serving web pages, the ip address is responding on port 80, what's the intermediate thing that I'm missing to link the two together?

Comment: Are you trying to access the public IP address from inside your network?

Comment: @DavidPostill I've tried both, internally it times out, I disconnect my phone from wifi and try it and I get "Error: Invalid request or server failure. HTTP_Proxy"

Comment: Internally will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: @David ... could it be done with a Tomato or DD-WRT router?

Comment: @Paulb No idea.

Comment: Hosting from home (my guess here) with consumer grade hardware is not a good idea in any event. Just wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, the IP address had changed. I used no-ip.com and set up a dynamic IP name for it.
And yes, it doesn't work from within my network.

Comment: I think you should add this as an [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1074530/edit) to your original post as it is more extra information for diagnostics.